# How to pick up object?

Tags: animation, rigging, keyframes

So imagine a scene. A character of mine is bending down grabbing a ball from the floor then standing up and throwing the ball.

I have the character rigged and ready with the action but how do i make the ball move with the character? Im hoping keyframing it in position isnt the way to do it as thats a nightmare?

In general im asking the best way for an character to pick up/throw/interact with an object... whats the best way to do this? (Once the character is created and rigged)

Comment: maybe my answer here will help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147240/how-can-i-make-my-animated-robot-pick-up-an-object-a-pole-during-an-animation/147249

Answer (score 4):

You add a "Child of" constraint to the ball, and select the armature and bone of the character you want to pick it up with.  You can then animate the **influence** of the constraint to change when the ball is influenced by the character.

hope this helps.