# Link constrain with multiple father change

Tags: animation

I need help to understand how to make what I use to do in 3DS max... I cannot find a similar solution in Blender:

I need to move a piece that is a "child of" a part until the frame 50. After this, I have to change the father of my piece starting from frame 51 until frame 100...and another time I have to change the father starting from frame 101.

The problem is that after the 2nd "child of" the piece doesn't change the father and come back with the movement of the previous father. It is clear?

Maybe is not "child of" the correct constrain?

Many thanks for our help.

Comment: I gave an answer here, maybe it will help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147240/how-can-i-make-my-animated-robot-pick-up-an-object-a-pole-during-an-animation/147249

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer...
It's correct but I have a step more...I need to put more than 1 constraint on the same piece because I have 2 or 3 robots and the piece is placed in different positions....so I think I have to put more than one "child of" on the same piece and I experiment some problem on this.
Practically I have to move the piece with the first robot and put it in a middle position...after this, the second robot takes that piece and bring it on another position...and so for 3 or more times...

Comment: ok...I've tried your previous post and it's really what I need. It's work.
The only thing is that I cannot understand why I have to put the location and after the visual location. Can you explain to me the differences between Location and VisualLocation? I cannot find anything around it...

Comment: ok I tried to give an explanation in the same answer, I hope it's understandable ;)   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147240/how-can-i-make-my-animated-robot-pick-up-an-object-a-pole-during-an-animation/147249